# Could you explain the conditional sentence Type 2 of this sentence "If I told you that I lived in Russia, you wouldn't believe it"

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

Ok,

> [Conditional sentence type 2](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/type-2-conditional/) refers to an unlikely or
>   hypothetical condition and its probable result. These sentences are
>   not based on the actual situation. In type 2 conditional sentences,
>   the time is now or any time and the situation is hypothetical.
>
> EXAMPLES
>
> If the weather wasn't so bad, we would go to the park. (But the
>   weather is bad so we can't go.)
>
> If I was the Queen of England, I would give everyone a chicken. (But I
>   am not the Queen.)
>
> If you really loved me, you would buy me a diamond ring.
>
> If I knew where she lived, I would go and see her.

But what about this sentence "**If I told you that I lived in Russia, you wouldn't believe it.**"

*How to explain it under the rule of conditional sentence type 2?*

I suspect conditional sentence type 2 can be used to express other things not just "**hypothetical situations**".

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. What do you need explained? The sentence you ask about is also a hypothetical situation.

Comment: Prompted, I assume, by this question and answer: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113421/what-are-the-differences-between-would-you-believe-it-dont-you-believe-it/113423#113423